# How do I fix a "Windows Workflow 3.0 required" error when editing a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 SP1?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a Windows 8.1 machine that needs to edit workflows within SharePoint Designer (2013 SP1).

Whenever a workflow is clicked on one of two errors is received:

1. Server side activities have been updated. You need to restart SharePoint Designer to use the updated version of activities.
2. Windows Workflow Foundation, part of .Net Framework 3.0 must be installed to use this feature.

   [image: Screenshot of Microsoft SharePoint Designer error message "Windows Workflow Foundation, part of .Net Framework 3.0, must be installed to use this feature.]

Restarting does nothing to correct the errors.

Several blogs or support sites have recommended deleting temporary files which hasn't helped. I have reinstalled SharePoint Designer as well.

Another Windows 7 machine is also having the same issue with the same site.

It seems to be an issue with the site. The site is hosted on SharePoint Online.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever managed to fix this. One of our Windows 7 workstations has been suffering from the same issue for months, but I never managed to crack it. (Most likely eventually going to do a clean install of Windows)

Comment: No, we stuck with using the workstations that didn't have the issue :(

Comment: Please check the below link for fixing this issue
https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/workflow-migration-error-sharepoint-designer-error/

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue for 3 months now, for no avail. I usually stumble upon @praveen suggested solution. But it just doesn't work.

Comment: Hi guys,did you found a solution?

Comment: am facing the same issue too... Please  help me, how to get rid of this weird issue!

Answer (score 5):

I followed directions on this website and was able to open my workflows again.

- https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/tag/net-framework-3-0-error/

Basically, I cleared the following caches and restarted SPDesigner:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

I also installed the Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB3114721) update.

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53389

Comment: Just installing the update fixed it for me  Much headache avoided 

Answer (score 1):

Installing the update above, ensuring that .NET Framework 3.0 was installed and then clearing the cache worked for me.

#Add Module
Install-Module -Name DotNetVersionLister -Scope CurrentUser #-Force

#Check to see which/if .NET is installed and what version
Get-STDotNetVersion

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error unexpectedly after years of using  SP designer on particular host with particular  workflow-enabled library. I've  tried all the solutions from this topic with my Windows10 but only my own worked.
Kind of shamanic magic:

1. Open another (sandbox) subsite of target site collection in designer.
2. Create 2013 simple list workflow on any library. Publish it.
3. Re-open target site in designer and workflow to edit. It shoud work. Test WF from step 2  can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing the .Net Framework 3.0 sp1 (not 3.5 or any 4.x) fixed it.
https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/windows-workflow-foundation-part-of-net-framework-3-0-must-be-installed-to-use-this-feature/

Answer (score 0):

Installing this update from Microsoft and then restarting fixed it for me.
[Download SharePoint Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53389)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  that did fix it for me.  Thanks

Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB3114721) 64-Bit Edition